# How to programmatically update lineHighlightBackground in vscode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm writing vscode extension. I want to update vscode configuration (doesn't matter if it's global or workspace config) programmatically, not manually.

The manual way works fine:

1. I press **F1**
2. I find >**Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)**
3. I go inside **"workbench.colorCustomizations"**
4. I update **"editor.lineHighlightBackground"** to **"#1073cf2d"**.

Can I do it programmatically?

I tried this:

```
vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("workbench.colorCustomizations")
.update("editor.lineHighlightBackground", "#5e0a69");
```

But does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works fine. I also added **lineHighlightBorder** changer next to the **lineHighlightBackground** changer.

```
let vvv: any = vscode.workspace
    .getConfiguration("workbench")
    .get("colorCustomizations");

vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("workbench").update(
    "colorCustomizations",
    {
        ...vvv,
        "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#1073cf2d",
        "editor.lineHighlightBorder": "#9fced11f",
    },
    1,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The **”workbench.colorCustomizations”** setting is an Object, so you can’t update just one line/property, but instead you must update the entire Object.

So, read the **“workbench.colorCustomizations”** setting (entire Object), manually update that property and later, update the **“workbench.colorCustomizations”** setting with the updated Object.